# apt-get update error for a personal repository

Tags: apt

I have a personal repository setup using `reprepro`. Everything works allright. `apt-get update` reads the package list from the repository and I can install packages from the repository. A few annoying error messages are printed though and I can't figure out how to resolve them (domain name removed):

```
Get:1 http://xxxxxx/packages/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en [3,401B]
99% [1 Translation-en bzip2 0B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
Ign http://xxxxxx/packages/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Get:4 http://xxxxxx maverick Release [1,243B]
60% [3 Translation-en_US bzip2 0B] [4 Release gpgv 1,243B]bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
```

Is this a problem with the way the repository is setup using `reprepro` or is this a local `apt-get` problem?

These are the releavant parts of the reprepro distributions file:

```
Suite: stable
Codename: maverick
Version: 10.10
Architectures: i386
SignWith: yes
Components: multiverse
DebIndices: Packages Release . .gz .bz2
UDebIndices: Packages . .gz .bz2
DscIndices: Sources Release .gz .bz2
DebOverride: override.maverick
UDebOverride: override.maverick
DscOverride: override.maverick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(stdin) is not a bzip2 file` error most probably means that the repository is not available anymore.

Now if you visit http://www.mydomain.nl/ (website for the repository), you will notice that the domain/webhosting expired and the website is not available anymore.

Therefore, unless they fix their website, you can remove the entry from your Package sources.

Comment: mydomain.nl is a dummy domain, in reality I use my company's website which is up and running. As I mention in the question, I can properly update and install packages.

Comment: Identify the .bz2 file and verify that it is a valid bz2 file. If apt-get still fails, then it is possible that in /var/cache/apt/ you have a bad cache of the bz2 file. You need to remove so that it gets downloaded again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The .bz2 files were missing on the server. Instead of returning a 404 error, a webpage was returned due to rewrite rules. Forcing a 404 error for missing files in the repository directories resolved the issue.